# Enter Unknown amount of variables in Java

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, variables

I have to create a small program using only if-else and loops, where a user enters how many numbers they are going to enter, enters all the numbers, and the program outputs the smallest number divided by the biggest. This is all in Java. This is what I have so far, I'm pretty new to this!

```
    double amtNum, doubleCnt, num;
    doubleCnt = 0;

    String dataIn;
    System.out.print("How many numbers would you like to enter: ");
    dataIn = input.readLine();
    amtNum = Integer.parseInt(dataIn);

    while (doubleCnt < amtNum){
        doubleCnt +=1;
        System.out.print("First Number: ");
        dataIn = input.readLine();
        num = Integer.parseInt(dataIn);
```

Comment: break down your problem and implement each part. You got the "getting the initial number" part done, but your loop to then get all those numbers is odd: why would you say "First number" when your loop is going to get _all_ numbers? Also, in the loop, you have the part that gets one number, so now add the code for storing that number in a list that can fit "as many numbers as your user said they were going to type".

Comment: Hint: If you want to process lots of "things", use a list or an array.  Java doesn't have a way of declaring an *indefinite* number of *variables*.

Comment: By reading the "title" i'm feeling that you are getting confused at how many variables you should declare so that you  can store all inputs given by user. @StephenC is correct you should look into arrays, lists, vectors. They are what you require here.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to remember all the entered values. At any given moment, you only need to keep track of a few values: the highest seen so far, the lowest seen so far, and the value that was just entered. You can forget about everything else you've seen.

You will also need to remember the total number of values the user will enter, and how many values have been entered so far. This will let you know when you are done, and you can perform your division.